# Swift Struct with Lazy, private property conforming to Protocol

Tags: swift, struct, protocols, lazy-evaluation

First, I have a protocol that defines only a few, readonly properties, ex:

```
protocol Example {
  var var1:String { get }
  var varArray:[String] { get }
}
```

I then want to create a struct that conforms to that protocol.  The problem I'm running into, is that I have two conflicting requirements:

1. The properties need to be lazily generated.
2. The properties are related and need to be generated together.

I can't seem to find a way to do this.  The closest I've come is something like this:

```
struct AStruct : Example {
  private lazy var data:(var1:String, varArray:[String]) = {
    var stringValue:String = ""
    var stringArray:[String] = []
    //Generate data
    return (stringValue, stringArray)
  }()

  var var1:String {
    return self.data.var1
  }

  var varArray:[String] {
    return self.data.varArray
  }
}
```

The problem is, I'm getting the error: `Immutable value of type 'AStruct' only has mutating members named 'data'`.

Does anyone know of a way I might be able to accomplish my goal?  Technically, the `data` variable is mutable but will never change.  I can't use `let` with `lazy` so I can't specify that the value will never change once it's been generated.  I need the values to be generated though, because the struct is created on the main thread, but the values will be generated on a background thread by another process altogether.

#### Update

So it was pointed out to me that I can make the getters `mutating` in both the protocol and the struct.  That works, except I now have the problem that I cannot use this struct in any other struct (which I am).  So in the end, I've pushed off the problem into another struct, which I do not want to be mutable.

Ex:

```
struct Container {
  let astruct:AStruct
  let callback:() -> ()
}
```

I cannot access the variables in `AStruct` from `Container` because `Container` is immutable and the member variables of `AStruct` are mutating.  Trying to access them gives me the same error message I spoke of earlier.

Changing the container to use `var` instead of `let` yields the same error:

```
struct Container {
  var astruct:AStruct
  let callback:() -> ()
}
```

If I set up a function in the processing class that receives a `Container` to process:

```
func processContainer(cont:Container){
  self.doSomething(cont.astruct.var1)
}
```

I get the same error: `Immutable value of type 'AStruct' only has mutating members names 'sql'`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because accessing the lazy `data` variable mutates `AStruct`, any access to it must be marked as also mutating the struct.  So you need to write:

```
struct AStruct : Example {
    // ...
    var var1: String {
        // must declare get explicitly, and make it mutating:
        mutating get {
            // act of looking at data mutates AStruct (by possibly initializing data)
            return self.data.var1
        }
    }

    var varArray:[String] {
        mutating get {
            return self.data.varArray
        }
    }
}
```

However, you'll find now that Swift complains you aren't conforming to `Example`, because its `get var1` isn't marked as mutating.  So you'd have to change it to match:

```
protocol Example {
    var var1:String { mutating get }
    var varArray:[String] { mutating get }
}
```

Comment: That almost works, except that these structs are stored in other structs (for later processing).  So now I'm getting `Immutable value of type 'AStruct' only has mutating members named 'var1'`.

Comment: That means you need to declare the `AStruct` variable in your containing struct (or the array that holds it etc.) with `var` rather than `let`.

Comment: You just moved the problem up a level. Now `cont` must be `var`. You cannot have lazy variables anywhere inside of a `let` struct. In my experience, lazy in structs seldom really works the way you would want it to. "let" means "I promise no byte in this value structure will change." So you're going to need a reference type in there somewhere if you want to be `let` at the top. (I consider this an overall failing in Swift.)

Comment: Sorry should have mentioned also that the functions in your container that access the mutating gets must _also_ be mutating.  As @Rob says, unfortunately `lazy` tosses all hopes of `let` out the window...  For sound reason though, as the compiler can no longer make assumptions it could in the case of genuine immutability.

Comment: `struct Container { var a = AStruct(); mutating func f() { println(a.var1) } }` compiles. Note, to call `f()`, `Container` must also be declared with `var`

Comment: So yeah, I'm going to have to rethink my approach.  I do agree with @RobNapier that this seems like a failing in Swift.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree that it's a failing – fundamentally, if a variable can change it's value, that's mutation.  The compiler can make all kinds of assumptions about truly immutable variables regarding things like substitutability, that it could not make if lazy variables were not considered mutation.

Comment: It's not so much that the failing is mutability, but that there's no way to truly create a lazy variable in an immutable object.  I agree that immutability should remain immutable.  But the whole idea of `let lazy` is that the value is set only once, and is immutable.  I don't think that's necessarily asking too much... but then, I also don't write compilers.

Comment: C++ has that concept of immutability, and you can create "observationally immutable" objects in C++ (rather than "memory-wise immutable" structs like in Swift). And Scala can have lazy properties on immutable objects. On the other hand, that surfaces issues like race conditions, which cannot happen in a pure-value Swift let-object (and I've struggled w/ that in Scala). But in practice so far, I haven't found a place that "lazy" is actually useful due to this. I wind up in the same places as Aaron, burying a class in there (so why bother having lazy?)

Answer (score 3):

So I want to detail out the solution I ended up following.  As it turns out, I don't think what I want is currently possible in Swift.  Once you start down the `mutating get` road, it ends up cascading into too many areas (all container structs need to be mutating, etc).  In the end, this kind of ruined the whole reason I wanted to use structs in the first place.

Perhaps down the road Apple will add a `lazy let var = ...`.  This would ensure immutability by guaranteeing the lazy variable is only ever set once... just not immediately.

So my solution was simply to forego `structs` altogether and use `classes` instead.  I keep the classes functionally immutable, so I still retain that. Quite literally, all I had to do was change `struct` to `class` and now the lazy construction works perfectly and all my problems go away... except I'm using a class.

All that said, @AirspeedVelocity has a correct solution, even if untenable for my needs, so I'll be accepting his solution.  I'm just leaving this here so others can understand how I overcame the problem... use classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve this by boxing the lazily allocated storage in a class. You just have to be careful that if somebody copies your struct, that the copy doesn't share the lazily allocated state, unless that makes sense. Here's an example:

```
class LazyValue<T> {
    var _storage : T?
    var body : () -> T
    var value : T {
        if let value = _storage {
            return value
        }
        let value = body()
        _storage = value
        return value
    }
    
    init(_ body : @escaping () -> T) { self.body = body }
}

struct StructWithLazyValue {
    let _lazyString = LazyValue<String> {
        "the date is = \(Date())"
    }
    
    var lazyString : String { _lazyString.value }
}
```

Technically, this doesn't mutate the struct at all, so you don't have to use mutating get. On the other hand, your struct now points at some shared state, which you might have to worry about when you copy it. You can use `isKnownUniquelyReferenced()` to implement copy-on-write, if that's a problem, but only from a mutating func/getter.