# Swift protocol with lazy property - Cannot use mutating getter on immutable value: '$0' is immutable

Tags: swift, protocols, lazy-loading

Goal: Create a protocol that allows lazy computation of a property for structs that conform to the protocol and then add the properties for an array of those structs. The computation is intensive and should only be executed once, hence the `lazy` requirement.

So, after lots of reading (eg this: [Swift Struct with Lazy, private property conforming to Protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28202834/swift-struct-with-lazy-private-property-conforming-to-protocol)) and trial and error (please don't flag this as a duplicate, unless it actually addresses this exact case), I came up with something that works:

```swift
import Foundation

protocol Foo {
    var footype: Double { mutating get }

    func calculateFoo() -> Double
}

struct Bar: Foo {
    private lazy var _footype: Double = {
        let value = calculateFoo()

        return value
    }()

    var footype: Double {
        mutating get {
            return _footype
        }
    }

    func calculateFoo() -> Double {
        print("calc")
        return 3.453
    }
}
```

Testing this in a Playground:

```swift
var bar = Bar()
print(bar.footype)
print(bar.footype)
```

And the output is:

```
calc
3.453
3.453
```

So far, so good.

Now, I want to make an array of `Bar` and add the `footype` properties:

```swift
var bar1 = Bar()
var bar2 = Bar()
var bar3 = Bar()
var bars = [bar1, bar2, bar3]

print(bars.map { $0.footype }.reduce(0.0, +))
```

Which gives me the following error:

> Cannot use mutating getter on immutable value: '$0' is immutable

Found a lot of info on this error, but am stuck how to solve it. One way would be to use `class` instead of `struct`, but that doesn't work well with other parts of the code.

Is it possible what I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can tell from the error message, `$0` is immutable, so you can't use a mutating member on it.

Therefore, you can't iterate over the `bars` directly. What you can do is iterating through its `indices`, because we know that `bars[$0]` *is* mutable:

```
print(bars.indices.map { bars[$0].footype }.reduce(0.0, +))
```

Comment: Any comments on my implementation of the `lazy` property?

Comment: @Koen You just seem to be using the solution in the linked answer, which is fine. However, I would not put `calculateFoo` in the protocol because it sounds like an implementation detail. You can post this on code review to get more feedback.

Comment: Posted here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/230651/swift-protocol-with-lazy-property-requirement